# Jsoup parsing html tag from page

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse pages (any page dynamic parser).
code is

```
Elements title = doc.select("title");
Elements metades = doc.select("meta[name=description]");
```

As you can see i want to extract title tag.

It is working fine on approx every website for example hinddroid.com
But it unable to parse Title from google.com and youtube.com
I think it is due to no space between two tags.
Most of big website not have space in html to save bandwidth.
Please suggest me - i want to parse html from website.

Full code :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class post_link extends HttpServlet 
{
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{

response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

try 
{
//out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" /><script src=\"http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.3.min.js\"></script><script src=\"jquery-social.js\"></script>");
String linktopro = "http://"+request.getParameter("link_topro");
//String linktopro = "http://hinddroid.com";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linktopro).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").timeout(3000).get();
Elements png = doc.select("img[src]");
Elements title = doc.select("title:first-child");
//Elements title = doc.title();
Elements metades = doc.select("meta[name=description]");
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("http://.*|.com*?.(com)");

out.println("<script> var myCars=new Array(");

for(Element pngs : png)
{
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(pngs.attr("src"));
boolean url = m1.matches();
String baseurl = "";
//out.println(url+"");
if(url)
{ baseurl = ""; }
else
{ baseurl = linktopro; }

out.println("\""+baseurl+""+pngs.attr("src")+"\",");
}
out.println("\"\"");
out.println(");</script>");

String outlink = "<div class=\"linkembox\">"+
"<div class=\"linkembox-img\">"+
"<img src=\"http://hinddroid.com/img/logo.gif\" width=\"150\" height=\"120\" />"+
"<br/><div id=\"linkimg-left\"><</div><div id=\"linkimg-right\">></div>"+
"</div>"+
"<div class=\"linkembox-text\">"+
"<div class=\"h\">"+title.html()+"</div><br/>"+
"<div class=\"h1\">"+metades.attr("content")+"</div>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>";
out.println(outlink);
out.print("<script> left(myCars); </script>");




}
catch(Exception ex)
{
out.print(ex);
} 
finally 
{
out.close();
}

}


}
```

Comment: Jsoup should work on any well-formed document. It shouldn't fail to parse titles from google and youtube. Paste your full code so that I can help you.

Comment: after getting the page, `doc.title()` should work fine for getting the title of the page.

Comment: Dear deadlock please review code
and shoshi i am going to try your solution

Answer (score 1):

I execute the selectors, it's fine. No problem at all!

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://facebook.com").get();

    System.out.println("Title: " + doc.title());
    System.out.println("Meta Description: " + doc.select("meta[name=description]").first().attr("content"));

}
```

With `google.com`, you can get only `<title>`, not `<meta name=description...` because it's not in HTML source.